# SwiftUI customButton / view alignement issue in HStack

Tags: button, swiftui, spacing, vstack, hstack

I have a row of custom buttons displayed in a VStack and a HStack, strangely the 2 rows are not aligning - see the example for the best I could achieve.
I suspect that it is due to the different content (text or SFSymbol) but the buttons "look" the same size.
To get this I had to have different spacing within the HStacks which.

Thanks

[image]

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MyRoundButton: ButtonStyle {

    var color: Color = .purple
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        
        configuration
        
            .label
            .frame(height: 30)
            .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .white : color)
            .padding(23)
            .background(
                Circle()
                    .fill(configuration.isPressed ? color : color.opacity(0.25)))
            
    }
}



import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 23) {
                Group {
                    Button {
                        
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "photo.fill.on.rectangle.fill")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton(color: .red))
                    
                }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton())
            }
            
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 27) {
                
                Group {
                    Button {
                        
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        
                        Text("Ja")
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton(color: .green))
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Ja")
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton(color: .blue))
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Ja")
                    }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton(color: .orange))
                    
                    Button {
                        print ("didTap roundButton")
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Ja")
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton(color: .yellow))
                    
                }.buttonStyle(MyRoundButton())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you give the buttons a fixed size?

Comment: You can use alinement without having to use a fixed size, or using 5 VStack and 1 HStack is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed size worked as suggested, thanks.

```
   import Foundation
   import SwiftUI
    
 

       struct MyRoundButton: ButtonStyle {
        
            var color: Color = .purple
            
            func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
                
                configuration
                    .label
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .white : color)
                    .padding(23)
                    .background(
                        Circle()
                            .fill(configuration.isPressed ? color : color.opacity(0.25)))
            }
        }
```